# How do I embed a child view within an NSTextView?

Tags: macos, cocoa, nstextview

I have a text view, in which I would like to place other views, like so:

```
=====================================
= This is an editable NSTextView... =
= /-------\                         =
= |Subview|                         =
= \-------/                         =
= other text.                       =
=====================================
```

There are `NSTextAttachment`s, but they seem to only be well-suited for images. How can I insert into the text a fully-functional `NSView` with keyboard/mouse interaction and subviews itself, etc?

Answer (score 2):

You might want to check out the [`NSTextContainer`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/applicationkit/classes/NSTextContainer_Class/Reference/Reference.html) and `NSLayoutManager` classes:

'*NSTextContainer defines rectangular regions, but you can create subclasses that define regions of other shapes, such as circular regions, regions with holes in them, or regions that flow alongside graphics.*'

'*An NSLayoutManager uses NSTextContainer to determine where to break lines, lay out portions of text, and so on.*'

The [Cocoa Text Architecture Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/TextFonts/Conceptual/CocoaTextArchitecture/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009459) might be handy as well.